# ArrayList replace element if exists at a given index?

Tags: java, arraylist

How to replace element if exists in an ArrayList at a given index?

Answer (score 189, accepted):

```
  arrayList.set(index i,String replaceElement);
```

Comment: here the question itself is - "replace element if exits", but to avoid error, null check required

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Collections-Data-Structure/ReplaceanelementatspecifiedindexofJavaArrayList.htm

Comment: is there any way without pass index in it??

Comment: @ArpitPatel arrayList.add() can be used to append a new element. You cannot specify where in the array list you want to add something without an index.

Answer (score 5):

If you're going to be requiring different set functionaltiy, I'd advise extending ArrayList with your own class. This way, you won't have to define your behavior in more than one place.

```
// You can come up with a more appropriate name
public class SizeGenerousArrayList<E> extends java.util.ArrayList<E> {

    @Override
    public E set(int index, E element) {
        this.ensureCapacity(index+1); // make sure we have room to set at index
        return super.set(index,element); // now go as normal
    }

    // all other methods aren't defined, so they use ArrayList's version by default

}
```

Answer (score 2):

An element is over-written if it already exists at an index, that is the default behaviour: [Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set%28int,%20E%29).

Or am I missing your point completely?

Answer (score 0):

just use this method inside arraylist

```
list.set(/*index*/,/*value*/)
```

Answer (score -1):

Just add a break after your *remove()* statement

Comment: Please can you provide complete answer, Thanks