# Issue trying to create a Bubble Sort using ArrayList<Integer>

Tags: java

Hi I'm trying to figure out how to use BubbleSort in Java and my code is erroring and I don't know why

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SortsRunner {

    public static void BubbleSort(ArrayList<Integer> nums) {
        ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int n = arr.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) 
            for (int j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++) 
                if (arr.get(j) > arr.get(j+1)) 
                { 

                    int temp = arr.get(j); 
                    arr.get(j) = arr.get(j+1); 
                    arr.get(j+1) = temp; 
                }
        }
    public static void SelectionSort(ArrayList<Integer> nums) {

        }
    public static void printArrayList(ArrayList<Integer> nums) {
        for(int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(nums.get(i) + " ");
            }
        System.out.println();
        }
    public static ArrayList<Integer> makeRandomArrayList() {
        ArrayList<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < (int)(Math.random() * 11) + 5; i++) {
            nums.add((int)(Math.random() * 100));
            }
        return nums;
        }

public static void main(String[] args) {
printArrayList(makeRandomArrayList());

}
```

}

When I get to `arr.get(j) = arr.get(j+1);` and `arr.get(j+1) = temp;` the left side errors saying "The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable." can anyone help me fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ArrayList replace element if exists at a given index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5617175/arraylist-replace-element-if-exists-at-a-given-index)

Comment: Use `.set()` not `.get()`.

Comment: You may want to use a `boolean` to determine if your inner loop did a swap.  If it didn't, the list is sorted.

Answer (score 2):

```
arr.get(j) = arr.get(j+1);
arr.get(j+1) = temp;
```

You're trying to assign a value to the result of a method call.

You just can't do this. You can only assign to a local variable, a field in the current class, a field access (e.g. `foo.bar = ...`) or an array element (e.g. `foo[0] = ...`).

Instead, you should use `set` to update a list element:

```
arr.set(j, arr.get(j+1));
arr.set(j+1, temp);
```

---

For the specific case of swapping two elements around in a list, you can instead use [`Collections.swap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#swap-java.util.List-int-int-):

```
Collections.swap(arr, j, j+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing several things wrong.

1. The obivous `get` and `set` issues already mentioned.
2. The fact that your are sorting an `empty list`. You pass in `nums` but sort the one you create which is empty.
3. You should use a `boolean` to prevent unnecessary repeats of the `outer loop`. Think of it like this, if you don't make a swap on the first iteration of the outer loop, then you won't swap on subsequent iterations.

And one style suggestion.  Don't use `loops` or `if statements` without `{}`.  Even if they only contain a single line of code.  You will be less likely to make coding errors if you do so.

Try the following:

```
    public static void BubbleSort(List<Integer> nums) {
        int n = nums.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            boolean swapped = false;
            for (int j = 0; j < n-1; j++) {
                if (nums.get(j) > nums.get(j + 1)) {
                    int temp = nums.get(j);
                    nums.set(j, nums.get(j + 1));
                    nums.set(j + 1, temp);
                    swapped = true;
                }
            }
            if (!swapped) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```